# Is a bundle build with webpack isolated from the other js on the page?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a very basic question about `Webpack` and `Javascript`.

If I want to bundle an application that is included other existing webpages, how can I be sure that the javascript code that I bundled and its dependencies do not collide with existing javascript code on these existing pages?

Is this done automatically by `Webpack`?

I wan't to provide a very small js component that can be included in arbitrary other sites for example via a  tag, but want to make sure that existing code of these sites that will use this component is not affected in unforeseen ways. How do i for example make sure that none of the dependencies that my component might have interfere with the global scope of the site?

Comment: it's not very clear. Do you want to use bundle with other js scrips at the same time?

Comment: @StanislavMayorov yes, sry i tried to add more explanation. I'm pretty new to modern javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use webpack bundle with other script at the same it. It doesn't use window object. Your code inside bundle will be isolated so you can use any dependencies.